# extract information from a log file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm still new to bash script , I have a log file and I want to extract the items within the last 5 days . and also within the last 10 hours

the log file is like this : it has 14000 items started from march 2002 to january 2003

is it possible to write it like this:

```
awk '{print $4}' < *.log |uniq -c|sort -g|tail -n
```

but still its not what I want

this is an example log file that i'm work on

```
172.16.0.3 - - [31/Mar/2002:19:30:41 +0200]
127.0.0.1 - stefan [01/Apr/2002:12:17:23 +0200]
213.64.153.92 - - [26/Sep/2002:02:01:58 +0200]
213.97.240.226 - - [28/Sep/2002:03:50:58 +0200] 
213.64.214.124 - - [29/Sep/2002:09:56:04 +0200]
.......
213.46.27.204 - - [01/Jan/2003:12:55:21 +0100]
```

Comment: Can you include a few example lines from the logfile in your question?

Comment: Why do you use `uniq -c`? And as ed wrote above, need a some example lines.

Comment: What is the information you want to extract? Awk's $4 will only get you the date stamp from each log entry; from your question I fathom you want to select lines based on date, but print something else.

Comment: I want to extract the last X hours/days from the log file

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using 'Perl'. I modified a little your input file. Test it:

Input file data:

```
$ cat ayda.txt
213.46.27.204 - - [15/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [16/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [17/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [18/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [19/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
```

Perl script:

```
$ cat script.pl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::Local;

my %MONTH = (
        Jan => 0,
        Feb => 1,
        Mar => 2,
        Apr => 3,
        May => 4,
        Jun => 5,
        Jul => 6,
        Aug => 7,
        Sep => 8,
        Oct => 9,
        Nov => 10,
        Dec => 11
);

my $SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60;
my $SECONDS_IN_DAY = $SECONDS_IN_HOUR * 24;

## Extract and check arguments.
@ARGV == 3 or die qq[Usage: perl $0 logfile [-d|-h] num\n];
my ($time, $option) = ( pop @ARGV, pop @ARGV );
die qq[ERROR: Invalid input arguments\n] if $time =~ /\D/;

## Get the utc time to filter data file.
my $current_utc = time;
my $param_utc;
if ( $option eq "-h" ) {
        $param_utc = $current_utc - $time * $SECONDS_IN_HOUR;
}
elsif ( $option eq "-d" ) {
        $param_utc = $current_utc - $time * $SECONDS_IN_DAY;
}
else {
        die qq[ERROR: Invalid input\n];
}

## When true, print data until eof.
my $in_time = 0;

while ( <> ) {
        if ( $in_time .. eof ) {
                print;
                next;
        }

        chomp;

        m|\[(\d{2})/(\w{3})/(\d{4}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})| || next;
        my $utc = timelocal( $6, $5, $4, $1, $MONTH{ $2 }, $3 - 1900 );
        if ( $param_utc - $utc <= 0 ) {
                $in_time = 1;
                print $_, qq[\n];
        }

}
```

Running the script:

```
$ perl script.pl
Usage: perl script.pl logfile [-d|-h] num
$ perl script.pl ayda.txt -d 4
213.46.27.204 - - [16/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [17/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [18/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [19/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
$ perl script.pl ayda.txt -h 30
213.46.27.204 - - [18/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
213.46.27.204 - - [19/Sep/2011:22:55:21 +0100]
```

Comment: I want to write it with sell script not perl and it seems that without the help of perl , it would be so difficult!

Comment: Your log file is a bit too messed up to do things in straight bash.  The hardest thing to get around is the date/time format -- half of the Perl script is just there to handle that.